# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) with duplicate symbols

Tags: ios

duplicate symbol _titleobj1 in:
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _imagObj in:
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _textObj in:
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _titleobj1 in:
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ViewController.o
duplicate symbol _imagObj in:
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ViewController.o
duplicate symbol _textObj in:
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ViewController.o
duplicate symbol _titleobj1 in:
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TableViewController.o
duplicate symbol _imagObj in:
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TableViewController.o
duplicate symbol _textObj in:
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TableViewController.o
duplicate symbol _titleobj1 in:
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DetailViewController.o
duplicate symbol _imagObj in:
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DetailViewController.o
duplicate symbol _textObj in:
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Tolly Gossips 2/ramesh/Build/Intermediates/HTMLParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HTMLParsing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DetailViewController.o
ld: 12 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Show us the declaration of, say, `imagObj`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like you have declared these objects globally...

- _titleobj1 (titleobj1)
- _imagObj (imagObj)
- _textObj (textObj)

Try to post the code for declaration of these variables, I will edit the answer for help. Else try to replace them totally.

In fact if you need these variables or objects for every controller, they should not be global. But I am not sure what you are trying to do unless I see your code.

Add the necessary code of declaration of the objects...

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.  Also the objects will not be declared with a leading underscore.

Comment: It contains an answer, with comment...

"In fact if you need these variables or objects for every controller, they should not be global. But I am not sure what you are trying to do unless I see your code."

And I am sure, that is the mistake the person is asking...

Comment: @juvvamahesh Please show what you changed to correct your linker errors.

Comment: i am upgrading old app to iphone 6 and i changed tha code because the old code is not parsing properly

Comment: @juvvamahesh But *what* did you change to correct the linker errors?

Comment: global variables only

Comment: in didselectrow at indexpath

Comment: they took the title tag and pubdate tag by using boolieans and like so now i am t implemetent elementname is equlto item i got the data on table view but i am unable to pass the data to detailview

Comment: so i use global variable to transfer the da